# List files present in remote server using ip address

Tags: java, android, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to list the files that are present in remote server using ip address. 
Something like this.

```
File folder = new File(<ip/>);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 
String files;

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
{
 if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
 {
   files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
   System.out.println(files);
 }
}
```

Please give some ideas.

Comment: no.. it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

You need to write some server side coding to generate the list of files in the server. Then your client can access that service to get the list of files

Answer (score 0):

You have to use`Android HTTP Access` for this. Read this [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html). it will helpful to you.